# How can I fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'similarity.normalized_levenshtein'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, nlp, levenshtein-distance

So I keep having this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'similarity.normalized_levenshtein' in my error log for some reasons.

This is what I was trying to do:

```
from similarity.normalized_levenshtein import NormalizedLevenshtein
normalized_levenshtein = NormalizedLevenshtein()
```

This is what was shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "API.py", line 10, in <module>
    import nlp3_model
  File "C:\Users\Admin\ai-challenge\nlp-3-api\fastml\lib\site-packages\import_ipynb.py", line 61, in load_module
    exec(code, mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'similarity.normalized_levenshtein'
(fastml)
```

I have already installed similarity, python-levenshtein, and Levenshtein according to what was in pip list.

Also it's weird because when I tried to run my .ipynb notebook with this line, it works fine, there were no errors. When I imported the .ipynb to a python file, there was this error. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the package several times and have already double-checked to see that it is in my venv.

I would really appreciate all the support. Thank you so much

Comment: Did you check wheater it relates to virtual environments or not?

Comment: I don't think it relates to venv but rather my virtual machines